# Adding, subtracting numbers in a textview

Tags: java, android

I would like to know if it's possible to add 2 or more numbers from within a textview, the best example i could think of is the stock android calculator. i have attached pictures of my app the first picture is where the app works perfect 
[image: so there when i press the calculate button it will add the 50 and the 55]

[image]

i would also like my app to do this (by adding 25+25 OR 25-5
i get a foreclose when i initiate the operation by clicking calculate.
could anyone please help me with this?? i have searched everywhere for the answer W/O any luck.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't post complete minimal code necessary to replicate the problem, I'm just guessing that you're getting the input as type String or CharSequence, and then you're trying to immediately turn it into a number, without first parsing it for the different parts.

Here's a simple example of parsing String input similar to what you're proposing to handle.  Note that I am not at all suggesting that this is how you should handle your inputs.  (I'm just planting a seed.)  In fact, parsing string inputs for calculator functions is a very popular topic for which many examples and different approaches can be found by Google searching.  (Also, note that some more "robust" calculator parsing functions will break the input into a tree or stack of operators and operands.)

```
public class Foo
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String input = "2+2";
    String[] parts = input.split("\\+");
    int operand1 = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
    int operand2 = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
    int result = operand1 + operand2;
    System.out.println(input + "=" + result);
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you i think this is what i need i just don't know where to put it is there anyway i could email you my code or show the code to you somehow. i'll try editing my post for now

Comment: As you've already accepted this answer, yet you posted new code above... Do you have another question?

Comment: yes sir i was wondering how to implement your solution into my code and please excuse my ignorance thank you bruce

Comment: Here's the line of code that does pretty much what I said I guessed you were doing before you posted the code. serviceCall = Double.parseDouble(serviceCallTxt.getText().toString());  If you change this to first do something like String input = serviceCallTxt.getText().toString(); then, combined with the example I posted above, do you start to see how to put the rest of the pieces together?

Comment: Also, back in the good old days at JavaRanch, Junilu Lacar created an excellent tutorial that covered a few topics, including TDD, OOP, and some other good stuff.  The tutorial was centered around implementing a calculator.  The links are a bit broken now, but if you Google search for OOCalculator at javaranch.com or coderanch.com, you can put the pieces together.  One page that lists the other pages (all with broken links, currently) is http://www.coderanch.com/t/97617/patterns/Listing-OOCalculator-OOCalc

Answer (score 0):

This requires that the app parse the text view contents and interpret it in terms of calculations it knows how to do. There is absolutely nothing in the api that would automatically parse and evaluate expressions typed into a text view.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to parse the text before transforming it to a number.

See http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=480122 and http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-scala10248/index.html for ideas